# как сделать чтобы выводило позицию не только 1 раз?

Tags: c++

как сделать чтобы выводило позицию не только 1 раз, то есть если есть текст binary seacrch is binary, то чтобы выводили позицию 2 binary

```
#include <stdio.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <math.h>
    #include <iostream>
    #include<string>
    using namespace std;
    
    #define tonum(c) (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z' ? c - 'A' : c - 'a' + 26)
    
    
    int mod(int a, int p, int m)
    {
        if (p == 0)
            return 1;
        int sqr = mod(a, p / 2, m) % m;
    
        if (p & 1)
            return ((a % m) * sqr) % m;
        else
            return sqr;
    }
    
    int RabinKarpMatch(char* T, char* P, int d, int q)
    {
        int i, j, p, t, n, m, h, found;
        n = strlen(T);
        m = strlen(P);
        h = mod(d, m - 1, q);
        p = t = 0;
    
        for (i = 0; i < m; i++)
        {
            p = (d * p + tonum(P[i])) % q;
            t = (d * t + tonum(T[i])) % q;
        }
    
        for (i = 0; i <= n; i++)
        {
            if (p == t)
            {
                found = 1;
                for (j = 0; j < m; j++)
                    if (P[j] != T[i + j])
                    {
                        found = 0;
                        break;
                    }
                if (found)
                    return i + 1;
            }
            else
            {
                t = (d * (t - ((tonum(T[i]) * h) % q)) + tonum(T[i + m])) % q;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }
    
    int main(int argc, char* argv[])
    {
        int sovp;
        int d = 1, q = 1000;
        char T[200];
        char P[100];
        string t;
        string p;
        cout << "Vvedite text" << endl;
        getline(cin, t);
        strcpy_s(T, t.c_str());
        cout << "Vvedite stroku" << endl;
        getline(cin, p);
        strcpy_s(P, p.c_str());
    
        sovp = RabinKarpMatch(T, P, d, q);
        if (sovp)
            cout << "Slovo naideno v " << sovp << " posizii";
        else
            cout << "Sovpadenii ne naideno!!!";
        system("pause");
        return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для получения всех найденных строк, можно вызывать функцию в цикле, передавая в качестве строки в которой ищут, исходную строку после позиции, в которой найдено совпадение:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  int sovp = 0;
  int d = 1, q = 1000;
  char T[200];
  char P[100];
  string t;
  string p;
  cout << "Vvedite text" << endl;
  getline(cin, t);
  strcpy_s(T, t.c_str());
  cout << "Vvedite stroku" << endl;
  getline(cin, p);
  strcpy_s(P, p.c_str());

  do
  {
    int prevSovp = sovp;
    sovp = RabinKarpMatch(T + sovp, P, d, q);
    if (sovp == -1)
    {
      if(!prevSovp)
        cout << "Sovpadenii ne naideno!!!";
      break;
    }
    sovp += prevSovp + 1;
    cout << "Slovo naideno v " << sovp << " posizii" << endl;
  } while (1);
  system("pause");
  return 0;
}
```

Я изменил функцию поиска, чтобы она возвращала -1, если ничего не найдено, и позицию найденного в противном случае:

```
int RabinKarpMatch(char* T, char* P, int d, int q)
{
  int i, j, p, t, n, m, h, found;
  n = strlen(T);
  m = strlen(P);
  h = mod(d, m - 1, q);
  p = t = 0;

  for (i = 0; i < m; i++)
  {
    p = (d * p + tonum(P[i])) % q;
    t = (d * t + tonum(T[i])) % q;
  }

  for (i = 0; i <= n; i++)
  {
    if (p == t)
    {
      found = 1;
      for (j = 0; j < m; j++)
        if (P[j] != T[i + j])
        {
          found = 0;
          break;
        }
      if (found)
        return i;
    }
    else
    {
      t = (d * (t - ((tonum(T[i]) * h) % q)) + tonum(T[i + m])) % q;
    }
  }
  return -1;
}
```

Непонятно зачем в цикле i может быть равно n (`i <= n`). Ошибка?